# Don't Allow Another Value In Dropdown To Be Selected in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I have a simple problem. Is there a way that if i could select a value from a dropdown and then when i add another row, that selected dropdown value cannot be selected anymore? Only values that are not selected will be available in the dropdown? Here's the link to my stackblitz below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-mtiiee?file=app/app.component.ts

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="ingredientData">
        <option value="null" hidden>-- Select Ingredient --</option>
        <option *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients" [ngValue]="ingredient">
            {{ingredient.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: why not to use `disabled` property for some set of conditions?

Comment: @PardeepJain. That would be fine. Can you do the code?

Comment: just working on the same code, posted by @pengyy as answer :)

Comment: @PardeepJain oops, sorry for that. Just a quick fix. I don't know whether it is convenient that the selected option is also disabled in current select.

Comment: @Pengyy Never mind ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether current option is already selected in value of form's `rows` form array and  set `disabled` to corresponding select option.

```
<option *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients" [ngValue]="ingredient" [disabled]="isSelected(ingredient)">

isSelected(ingredientData) {
  return this.addForm.get('rows').value.find(item => ingredientData === item.ingredientData);
}
```

Refer **[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-ejh9eb?file=app/app.component.ts)**.

Comment: Can you make it disappear?

Comment: @Joseph `disppear` means don't event show in select?

Comment: I mean instead of disabling the values in dropdown, make it disappear instead?

Comment: @Joseph you can do `filter` job at `*ngFor` expression. But based on your current code, it'll be wired when there is no item in select. see https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-3xwgni?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Penggy. I cannot see anymore the values in dropdown?

Comment: @Joseph that is because the selected option has been removed from select's options. Let me fix it.

Comment: @Joseph Fixed by setting hidden on option, but same problem when there is no options in select. see https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-n4gxy9?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks. Can you also hide the "add row" button if all the values in dropdown are selected? How can i do it? –

Comment: @Joseph just compare between your select options array and `rows` form array. see https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-82ti5c?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks. Excellent Work